# Get request for Millennial Media Advertisement in my Blackberry app

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, ads, get-request, millennial-media

I am trying to make a blackberry get request for advertisement from millennial media, I would love some help I cant seems to get it to work. This is what I have:

```
String url ="http://ads.mp.mydas.mobi/getAd?apid=157899&auid=ddd25abbb993f79454b12827c803fbafab2ad89b";
    try {                 
    conn = (HttpConnection) new ConnectionFactory().getConnection(url).getConnection(); conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);                 
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Profile/MIDP-1.0 Confirguration/CLDC-1.0");                 
    if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {                     
    in = conn.openInputStream();                     
    // parser.parse(in, handler);                  
    buff.append(IOUtilities.streamToBytes(in));                     
    result = buff.toString();
    } 
    else {                     
        result = "Error in connection" + conn.getResponseCode();
        ((ButterflyScreen)screen).update(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try{ if (in !=null) 
        {in.close();
        }
    conn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {                     
            e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

Here is my complete code for the class am trying to implement the get request.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.rmi.*;

import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;

import net.rim.blackberry.api.browser.Browser;
import net.rim.device.api.io.IOUtilities;
import net.rim.device.api.io.transport.ConnectionFactory;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap;
import net.rim.device.api.system.Display;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.XYEdges;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.HorizontalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.VerticalFieldManager;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.Background;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.BackgroundFactory;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.BorderFactory;


import com.ctpl.butterfly.custom.HrefField;


/**
* A class extending the MainScreen class,This is Home Screen on App.
*/
public final class ButterflyScreen extends MainScreen {
private ButtonField btnSetting;
private LabelField lblMsgNameOfApp, lblMsgDesc, lblHeading;
private HrefField lblMsgWebLink;
private Bitmap borderBitmap;
ButterflyScreen screen;
HttpConnection conn = null;             
InputStream in = null;             
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();             
String result = ""; 


/**
 * Creates a new ButterflyScreen object
 */
public ButterflyScreen() {
    super(VERTICAL_SCROLL|VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
    this.getMainManager().setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createLinearGradientBackground(0x0099CCFF,
            0x0099CCFF,0x00336699,0x00336699)
            );

    lblHeading = new LabelField(StringRes.APP_NAME) {
        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
    };      

    HorizontalFieldManager topPannel = new HorizontalFieldManager(
            Field.FIELD_HCENTER | Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH) {
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);

            int x = getWidth() / 2;
            x = x - lblHeading.getWidth() / 2;
            int y = 0;
            setPositionChild(lblHeading, x, y);
            setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(Bitmap.getBitmapResource("footer_back.png")));
        }

    };
    lblHeading.setFont(lblHeading.getFont().derive(Font.BOLD));
    topPannel.add(lblHeading);
    setTitle(topPannel);

    lblMsgNameOfApp = new LabelField(StringRes.WORLD+" \n") {
        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            graphics.setColor(Color.PURPLE);
            super.paint(graphics);
        }
    };

    lblMsgDesc = new LabelField(StringRes.WELCOME_SCREEN_MESSAGE+" \n");

    lblMsgWebLink = new HrefField("© Carib Tech Production Limited");
    lblMsgWebLink.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage("http://caribtechprod.com");
        }
    });
    btnSetting = new ButtonField(StringRes.SETTING_SCREEN);
    btnSetting.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {

        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new SettingWaitScreen());
        }
    });

    setDescScreen();

}

private void setDescScreen() {


    VerticalFieldManager vfmForCenterDisplay = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Field.FIELD_HCENTER | Field.FIELD_VCENTER ) {
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
            int topSpace = (Display.getHeight() / 8);
            setPadding(topSpace, 0, 0, 0);

        }
    };
    vfmForCenterDisplay.setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createLinearGradientBackground(0x0099CCFF,
            0x0099CCFF,0x00336699,0x00336699)
            );
    // Please verify this image src
    borderBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("img/rounded-border.png");
    VerticalFieldManager vfmBasicInfoWithBorder = new VerticalFieldManager() {
        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
            super.sublayout(maxWidth, maxHeight);
            Background background = BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE);
            setBackground(background);
        }
    };
    vfmBasicInfoWithBorder.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 5);

    vfmBasicInfoWithBorder.add(lblMsgNameOfApp);
    vfmBasicInfoWithBorder.add(new LabelField());
    vfmBasicInfoWithBorder.add(lblMsgDesc);

    vfmBasicInfoWithBorder.add(new LabelField());
    vfmBasicInfoWithBorder.add(lblMsgWebLink);

    HorizontalFieldManager hfm1 = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
    hfm1.add(btnSetting);


    vfmBasicInfoWithBorder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBitmapBorder(new XYEdges(12, 12, 12, 12), borderBitmap));

    ***String url ="http://ads.mp.mydas.mobi/getAd?apid=157899&auid=ddd25abbb993f79454b12827c803fbafab2ad89b";
    try {                 
    conn = (HttpConnection) new ConnectionFactory().getConnection(url).getConnection(); conn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);                 
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Profile/MIDP-1.0 Confirguration/CLDC-1.0");                 
    if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {                     
    in = conn.openInputStream();                     
    // parser.parse(in, handler);                  
    buff.append(IOUtilities.streamToBytes(in));                     
    result = buff.toString();
    } 
    else {                     
        result = "Error in connection" + conn.getResponseCode();
        ((ButterflyScreen)screen).update(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try{ if (in !=null) 
        {in.close();
        }
    conn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {                     
            e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}***


    VerticalFieldManager verticalFieldManager = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER|Field.FIELD_VCENTER);
    add(verticalFieldManager);

    VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager
            (VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL 
            | VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR 
            | VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
        HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager
            (HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER 
            | HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_VCENTER);

        hfm.add(verticalFieldManager);
        vfm.add(hfm);
        add(vfm);

    //vfmForCenterDisplay.add(new ButtonField("test"));

    vfmForCenterDisplay.add(vfmBasicInfoWithBorder);
    vfmForCenterDisplay.add(hfm1);

    add(vfmForCenterDisplay);
}

**private void update(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    VerticalFieldManager verticalFieldManager = new VerticalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_HCENTER|Field.FIELD_VCENTER);{

        VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager
                (VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL 
                | VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR 
                | VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
            HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager
                (HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER 
                | HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_VCENTER);

            hfm.add(verticalFieldManager);
            vfm.add(hfm);
            add(vfm);

    }

}**

public boolean onClose() 
{
    setDirty(false);
    return true;
}
```

}

I have place *** at place that am not sure about, I need your help with this please.

Comment: just print the values of the string result ? you getting any values on variable result ?

Comment: I haven't tried it because am getting a error in the result section when am writing it, so I not able to compile the app. I think the get request part is ok but how to display the result on the screen, that am not too sure about.